# Importing scientific data with uncertainties and units

Tags: import, data, units, uncertainty

I want to import scientific data from a CSV file. The data are length measurements in centimeters with uncertainties. I want to import the data with uncertainties and units into a vector - please see the code below. I can do this without units, but I am stuck how to do this with units for the whole data set. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

```
Remove["Global`*"];
data=Import["data.csv","CSV", "HeaderLines"->2];
TableForm[{Transpose[data]}, TableHeadings->{None,{"x (cm)","dx(cm)"}}]
```

[image]

```
x=VectorAround[data[[All,1]],data[[All,2]]]
```

[image]

I want to add units (cm) to variable x. I want it to be
VectorAround[{49.9 cm, 60.2 cm, 70.1 cm, 79.8 cm , 90. cm, 100.2 cm }, {0.1 cm, 0.1 cm, 0.1 cm, 0.1 cm, 0.2 cm, 0.2 cm}].

For example, I can do this manually for two data points:

```
x=VectorAround[{Quantity[data[[All,1]][[1]],"Centimeters"],Quantity[data[[All,1]][[2]],"Centimeters"]},{Quantity[data[[All,2]][[1]],"Centimeters"],Quantity[data[[All,2]][[2]],"Centimeters"]}]
```

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? This would be highly impractical to do manually with a large data set.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Try applying the function `Quantity[]` to the entire list of data. I think it has listable attributes meaning it should operate on all members of your data list

Comment: Quantity[VectorAround[data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]], "Centimeters"] does not produce the desired output, unfortunately. It does not seem to operate on all members of the list. It gives VectorAround[{49.9, 60.2, 70.1, 79.8, 90., 100.2}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2}] cm.

Comment: Try doing it to the data first

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load `data` with a few more entries, so forum participants can experiment with it. Or you can include a 1-click link to a downloadable csv file. Use an online service such as Dropbox or Google drive and make sure the link is public. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and it actually works! VectorAround[
 Quantity[data[[All, 1]], "Centimeters"],
 Quantity[data[[All, 2]], "Centimeters"]]       Thanks!

Comment: @user90441 sure, but you are duplicating code. You don't need to do `Quantity` twice.

Comment: @rhermans: you're right. Your solutions is a bit more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Table[
  {k + RandomReal[{-1,1}*k/500], Round[k/500, 0.1]}
  , {k, 50, 100, 10}
]

VectorAround @@ Quantity[
  Transpose@data
  , "Centimeters"
  ]

(* VectorAround[
{
  Quantity[49.9561, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[59.9273, "Centimeters"], Quantity[69.8579, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[79.977, "Centimeters"], Quantity[89.8892, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[99.9217, "Centimeters"]
},
{
  Quantity[0.1, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[0.1, "Centimeters"], Quantity[0.1, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[0.2, "Centimeters"], Quantity[0.2, "Centimeters"], 
  Quantity[0.2, "Centimeters"]
}
]*)
```

Or, if you don't want a vector,

```
Quantity[
 Around @@@ data
 , "Centimeters"
 ]

(* {Quantity[(
Around[49.956130623394806`, 0.1]), "Centimeters"], Quantity[(
Around[59.92730212004165, 0.1]), "Centimeters"], Quantity[(
Around[69.85785754443056, 0.1]), "Centimeters"], Quantity[(
Around[79.97703513294425, 0.2]), "Centimeters"], Quantity[(
Around[89.88924493447557, 0.2]), "Centimeters"], Quantity[(
Around[99.9217340877855, 0.2]), "Centimeters"]} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works:

```
VectorAround[
 Quantity[data[[All, 1]], "Centimeters"],
 Quantity[data[[All, 2]], "Centimeters"]]
```

Thanks for the help everyone!!!